# jhipster gateway not routing requests to microservice

Tags: java, api, microservices, jhipster

I am trying to create app with microservice architecture. I am using jhipster. I want to separate backend and frontend. So first i created jhipster uaa server for authorization named as **uaa** then i created a gateway with **--skip-client** and **--skip-user-management** options named as **gateway**. After running them both i can be login with postman with **/auth/login** api. But when i want to get account information i am getting api not found error. I am trying to get account information with **/uaa/api/account** link because microservices's name is uaa but no luck. Am i missing something or is there any other settings that forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before **/uaa** is missing **/services**, on the end is gonna be something like **/services/uaa/api/account** .

Comment: thank you for your answer, you are right, yesterday i noticed that there is a prefix settings in application.yml. i commented it and it worked as i wantted.